# TypeError: mousePos() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: function, python-2.7, typeerror

I've been trying to figure out how to fix this error. This is the first time I ran into an error like this. I've searched all over Google and I cant find a way to fix this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Parent\Desktop\NEW PROJECT\code testing and practice.py", line 49, in  <module>
print startGame()
File "C:\Users\Parent\Desktop\NEW PROJECT\code testing and practice.py", line 30, in    startGame
mousePos(304, 197)
TypeError: mousePos() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)


def leftClick():
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
time.sleep(.1)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
print "Click."         

def leftDown():
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
time.sleep(.1)
print 'left Down'

def leftUp():
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
time.sleep(.1)
print 'left release'
```

This is were I'm getting my error:

```
def mousePos(cord):
win32api.SetCursorPos(x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])

def get_cords():
x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
x = x - x_pad
y = y - y_pad
print x,y

def startGame():

#location of first menu
mousePos(304, 197)
leftClick()
time.sleep(.1)

#location of second menu
mousePos(338, 394)
leftClick()
time.sleep(.1)

#location of third menu
mousePos(576, 453)
leftClick()
time.sleep(.1)

#location of fourth menu
mousePos(311, 397)
leftClick()
time.sleep(.1)

print startGame()
```

Comment: The error is telling you that 'def mousePos(cord)` takes one argument `cord`, while you are passing two `mousePos(311, 397)`.

Answer (score 1):

the function mousePos takes one argument cord, it looks like a tuple or a list, you give two integer arguments. Try mousePos((x, y)), x, y are your location

Answer (score 1):

Put the coordinates in a tuple.

```
mousePos((311, 397))
```

Comment: thx now i know what to do if i runinto something like that again